# How do I fix: AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I am currently working on a twitter sentiment analysis project using BERT and HuggingFace transformer library. When it comes to training the model, I am facing this error:

```
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Upon searching on solutions online, such as this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771868/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-when-calculating-acc),  I learned that in most cases, I just have to change the axis to 0. However, it does not work for me.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

Evaluate function:

```
def evaluate(dataloader_val):

    # evaluation mode
    model.eval()
    
    # tracking variables
    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []
    
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader_val):
        
        # load into GPU
        # to(device) unpacks DataLoader into GPU
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        # define inputs
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2]}

        # compute logits
        with torch.no_grad():        
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        # compute loss
        loss = outputs[0]
        logits = outputs[1]
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        # compute accuracy
        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = inputs['labels'].cpu().numpy()
        predictions.append(logits)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
    
    # compute average loss
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val) 
    
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)
            
    return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals
```

Training the Model:

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):

    # set model in training mode
    model.train()

    # tracking variable
    loss_train_total = 0
    
    # set up progress bar
    # tqdm = to track progress
    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, 
                        desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), 
                        leave=False, 
                        disable=False)
    
    for batch in progress_bar:
        # set gradient to 0
        model.zero_grad()

        # load into GPU
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

        # define inputs
        inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels': batch[2]}
        
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss = outputs[0] #output.loss
        loss_train_total +=loss.item()

        # backward pass to get gradients
        loss.backward()
        
        # clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0 to prevent exploding gradients
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        
        # update optimizer
        optimizer.step()

        # update scheduler
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})     
    
    tqdm.write('\nEpoch {epoch}')
    
    # print training result
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)
    tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    
    # evaluate
    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_val)
    
    # f1 score
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(np.argmax(predictions, axis=0), np.argmax(true_vals, axis=0))
    tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
    tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (weighted): {val_f1}')
```

I am facing the error for this line:

```
val_f1 = f1_score_func(np.argmax(predictions, axis=0), np.argmax(true_vals, axis=0))
```

Comment: Could you check if the error happens in the argmax of predictions or argmax of true_vals? - just try and execute both statements separately before the line that throws the error

Comment: Also, what shape of predictions and true_vals have?

Comment: hi, when i do an argmax of predictions or true_vals, i would get the error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets` despite changing the axis to 0 as well @koegl