# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 (OneHotEncoded python)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, one-hot-encoding

Im working on a clasification model for dog breeds and Im trying to display examples of labels and their respective one hot encoded label but im getting an error saying that AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7u2Z.png)

Here is my current code:

```
    def decode_one_hot(one_hot_encoded, labels):
        # Use numpy's argmax to get the index of the '1' in each encoded list
        indices = np.argmax(one_hot_encoded, axis=1)
    
        # Convert indices back to original labels
        decoded_labels = [labels[index] for index in indices]
        return decoded_labels

    print('Example of label and one_hot_encoded label')
    train_labels = decode_one_hot(y_train, breeds)
    show_images(image_array= X_train, labels=train_labels, encoded_labels=y_train)
```

This is what i expected to achieve:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pySU0.png)

Comment: What is the shape of `y_train` and what is `breeds`?

Comment: The shape of y_train is 526 and breeds are the classes of dog breeds in my directory
'''
    path = "C:\\Users\\E\\Downloads\\Dog_Breed_Dataset\\data"
    breeds = os.listdir(path)
    os.listdir(path)

    breeds.sort()# Sorting is needed due to correction of labeling

    print()
    print('after sorted')
    print(breeds)
'''

Comment: Wait, if `y_train` is 1D why are you trying to call `np.argmax()` on its second dimension?

Comment: i've changed the way i converted my list to numpy arrays from y = np.array(data['label']) to y = np.array(y) and now y_train is 2D

Comment: That is still 1D though, if `data['label']` is 1D it's going to remain 1D, you can check with `print(np.shape(y))`

Comment: I'm insisting on this because if you get that error it means you are trying to access a dimension that the array doesn't possess

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771868/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-when-calculating-acc)

Comment: when i changed it to y = np.array(y) instead of y = np.array(data['label']) it somehow worked though, although one of my plots wont work when i changed to that. I've tried changing the axis = 0 as well, but i had another error which is "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: An `IndexError` happens because you're trying to access an element with an index larger than the list size. are `labels` and `indices` the same size? Where is the error coming from? This is too hard to debug like this. You should probably use a debugger or for each line of your code print what each variable is with its own shape and see if it makes sense. And ask here questions with a minimal verifiable example, as I can't run your code so I have no clue how to help you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your array is one-dimensional, in that case the syntax would be:

```
indices = np.argmax(one_hot_encoded, axis=0)
```